# Creating a print function to display an original array and an updated array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops

I am trying to figure out how get a print function to display an original array (I already have the original array displayed) and an updated array at the same time. I am slow at learning the proper syntax of c++, so I tend to forget the little details. I am trying to get my program to display a new list of values such as:

The new list of values:
4.0, 2.0 3.0 1.0

after using my `swapFirstLast(double a[], int n)` function. It is supposed to supposed to swap the first value with the last value of they array. The original list displays  1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 as a the original values.

So in the end it should be:

The list of values:
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0

The new list of values:
4.0 3.0 2.0 1.0

as well as the median, but I am trying to figure that out on my own until I absolutely need help (the reason why I post questions). Thank you for your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;



int main()
{ int i, count=0;
  double scores [10];
  double value;
  double sum=0.0;



cout << "Author: \n";

    cout<< fixed << showpoint <<setprecision(1);//

    cout<<"Input -1.0 when you are ready to stop."<<endl;
    cout<<"Input a value: ";

    cin>>value;

    while( value!= -1.0 && count<10)
        { scores [count] = value;
          count = count +1;

         cout<<"Input a value: ";
         cin>> value;

            }

    cout<<"\nYou entered "<<count<<" values"<<endl;


    for (i=0; i<count; i++)
    { cout<<setw(6)<< scores[i];
      sum+=scores[i];


    }
    cout<<"\n\nThe average of the values is:"<<sum/count<<endl;





    return 0;

}

void swapFirstLast(double a[], int n)
    { double temp;
        temp= a[0];
        a[0] = a[n-1];
        a[n-1]=temp;

}

void print( double a[], int n,double temp, int main())

    { double value;
        cout<<"The list of values: "<<value<<endl;
        cout<<"The new list of values: "<<temp<<endl;


}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. If you need both old and new values displayed, why not display before and after an update?

Comment: Or make a copy of the array before updating it, and use that to print the before version (although I'd recommend @n.m.'s approach, if that does the job).

Comment: put some comments in your code, and make exactly clear what you want to do

Comment: I am just trying to display that list when I execute the program. I only get the original list printed, however.

Answer (score 0):

You already have code that outputs the array. Only exclude the calculation of sum

```
for (i=0; i<count; i++)
    { cout<<setw(6)<< scores[i];
      sum+=scores[i];
}
```

You can place this code in a function

```
void print( const double a[], int n )
{
   for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
   {
      cout << setw(6) << a[i];
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

You should not include in this function some other code that does other tasks except the printing.

So at first you will call the function to print out the original array. Then you will call your swap function and then again call function print to print out the changed array.